# Typescript - how to implement circular generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, circular-reference, self-reference

I have the following code:

```
interface BaseProps<TControl> {
  onEvent: (control: TControl) => void;
}

class BaseControl<TValue, BaseProps<any>> {
  onBlur = () => {
    onEvent(this); //subscriber must see the whole TS-class instead of BaseControl<TValue, BaseProps<any>>
  }
}
```

As you can see I can't define class kind of

```
class BaseControl<TValue, BaseProps<this>>> {}
```

or infinite

```
class BaseControl<TValue, BaseProps<BaseControl<TValue, BaseProps<...etc.>>>> {}
```

Is there any way to implement the similiar generic pointer kinda ? `BaseProps<this>`

Comment: I ran into the same. Did you find a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
class Foo<T> { }
```

`T` is a *type variable*. It can not be a type itself. Which means you can have the above, but you can't have this

```
interface Foo<T> { } // ok
class Bar<any> { } // error: type variable cannot be 'any'
class Baz<Foo<any> { } // error: type variable cannot be 'Foo<any>'
```

which is what you're trying to do.

However, you can reference the type of `this` inside of the class itself

```
class Foo<T> {
    foo: Foo<T>;
    constructor(foo: Foo<T>) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

I can't help you further because your question is unclear, it looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but basically you should use the above.